# How to identify a client in node js?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to make a subscription system with a free period trial granted after subscription.

I need to avoid a user create a new account after his trial end to get another free trial.

I've used nodejs `serial-number` library but it works only on `localhost`. When my app is deployed on heroku I get a blank value as serial number.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: There is no way to conclusively identify unique clients.

Comment: You should verify something that costs a user more than they save through your free subscription. For example, register their phone number and send a verification text message before starting the free subscription.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen is this possible with node js to get the client ipv6 address ?

Comment: Phone number has got nothing to do with IPv6 address. Ask users to provide their mobile phone number. (Be sure to comply with all data protection and privacy regulations!) I fear that the hassle this gives you costs you more than the subscription itself.